# What is the lowest bound for the algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Let an algorithm which get unsorted array with the size of `n`. Let a number `k<=n`. The algorithm prints the k-smallest numbers from 1 to k (ascending). What is the lower bound for the algorithm (**for every k**)?

1. `Omega(n)`
2. `Omega(k*logn)`
3. `Omega(n*logk)`
4. `Omega(n*logn)`
5. #1,#2 Are both correct.

Now, from my understanding, if we want to find a lower-bound to an algorithm we need to look at the worst-case. If that the case, then obviously the worst-case is when `k=n`. We know that sorting an array is bounded by `Omega(nlogn)` so the right answer is #4.

Unfortunately, I am wrong and the right answer is #5.

Why?

Comment: I think you're confusing [Big Omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) with [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). `Omega(...)` means the algorithm runs that fast in the *best* case, not the worst.

Comment: Observe #1: It is not true that for every `k` the algorithm can run in `Omega(n)`. For example, `k=n` means we're practically sorting an array and that's bounded by `Omega(nlogn)`.

Comment: @Jon *Omega(...) means the algorithm runs that fast in the best case, not the worst.* That's incorrect. Big Omega says something about a function being asymptotically bounded below by another function, but this concept can be applied equally to any kind of asymptotics (best, worst-case, average, etc.). In other words, Big O and Big Omega are completely orthogonal to the type of complexity.

Comment: @AlonAlon Omega is an asymptotic lower bound, so n*logn is also Omega(n).

Comment: @Jubobs you're right, I simplified it too much. My point was that finding a lower-bound for the algorithm would imply using the best case, since that is the lowest run time the algorithm will take. Using the worst case, it's possible to end up with a run time that is higher than the lower bound, which would make Omega of that time incorrect.

Comment: @fgb, I understand that we can find the k-th smallest number in `O(n)` using the select algorithm. Then, we have to sort the subarray `[0-(k-1)]`. It takes `O(klogk)`. So all in all we have `O(n klogk)`. That being said, Why is the correct answer is #5?

Comment: The lower bound has to be valid for every `k`. If `n = k` then `nlogk` is a lower bound, but when `k = 1` then this bound is too high because the algorithm can run in `O(n)`.

Comment: @fgb, "The lower bound has to be valid for every k" - So how can it be that the answer is #5? I am probably missing something here..

Comment: @Jon There are worst-case big-Omega bounds and best-case big-O bounds. The O versus Omega specifies from what side the curve is asymptotically bounded, not the circumstances under which that bound is valid/achieved.

Comment: @Sneftel That's essentially what I meant, but you explained it much better.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in `O(n + klogk)`.

- Run selection algorithm to find the k smallest element - O(n)
- Iterate and return the elements lower/equals k - O(n)
- Another iteration might be needed in case of the array allows
  duplicates, but it is still done in O(n)
- Lastly, you need to sort these elements in `O(klogk)`

It is easy to see this solution is optimal - cannot get better than `O(klogk)` factor because otherwise for assigning k=n you could sort any array better, and a linear scan at least is a must to find the required elements to be printed.

Comment: The k numbers need to be sorted, so it would take more than that if you're only allowed to perform comparisons.

Comment: @interjay Missed the array got to be sorted part. let me add it.

Comment: @amit, I understand your analysis. BUT, I don't understand why the answer is #5. Can you explain it please?

Comment: Actually `klogk` sorting is for sorting algorithms using comparisons. I believe the correct answer is one since for every combination of `k` we need `Omega(n)` operations. And with `k = 1` we need exactly so many.

Comment: @AlonAlon I have no idea what Omega(klogn) and Omega(n) means, do they mean `Omega(n + klogn)` - if so, this is incorrect, since we found an answer which is NOT in this complexity class

Answer (score 1):

Lets try with **Linear time**:

1. In order to find the k'th smallest element, we have to use "Randomized-Select" which has the average running time of `O(n)`. And use that element as pivot for the quick sort.
2. Use Quick sort method to split the `array[i] <= k` and `array[i]>k`. This would take `O(n)` time
3. Take the unsorted left `array[i]<=k` (which has k elements) and do counting sort, which will obviously take O(**k**+K)
4. Finally the print operation will take `O(k)`

Total time = `O(n)+O(k+K)+O(k)` = `O(n+k+K)`

Here, **k** is the number of elements which are smaller or equal to K

Comment: There is at least one algorithm allowing point `1.` - it isn't quicksort, which in its classic form is O(n²).

Comment: @greybeard Worst case of quick sort is `O(n^2)` and the expected case is `O(nlogn)` as we all know iff we use quick sort to sort an array completely. But just one iteration is enough to split the array into 2 to get the smaller elements on one side and larger on the other. so the time that runs one step of quick sort would be `Θ(n)`.

Comment: How do you know `k` (as you are using it in your answer, which is different from how it is introduced in the question)?

Comment: @greybeard made the necessary edits to the answer. And it can be done still with linear time.